# Solve and Reduce gives different result

Tags: equation-solving

If Solve and Reduce gives totally different results, which one I shall trust? (The results from Solve look more reasonable.)

$\sum_{k = 19} ^{59} \binom{39}{k} p^k (1-p)^{39-k} =0.1 $ and I try to solve a real number $p$.

In:= Solve[ $\sum_{k = 19} ^{59} \binom{39}{k} p^k (1-p)^{39-k} =0.1, p, $ Reals]

Out:= {{p -> 0.374509}}

when i use Reduce, it gives me

In:= Reduce[ $\sum_{k = 19} ^{59} \binom{39}{k} p^k (1-p)^{39-k} =0.1, p, $ Reals]

Out:= p == 1.

Which result is correct?

Comment: Please paste code rather than LaTeX. See https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951

Comment: [O Perfidious Polynomial!](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Wilkinson.pdf) You probably should not deal with such high degree polynomials in machine precision. It's easy enough to write `1/10` instead of `0.1`. Exact solvers like `Solve` and `Reduce` use methods based on exact input. They both might fail on approximate, machine-precision inputs. I wouldn't trust either result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is too less digits in `0.1`. Compare with

```
f[p_] := Sum[Binomial[39, k] p^k (1 - p)^(39 - k), {k, 19, 59}];
Reduce[f[p] == 0.1000000000000000000, p, Reals]
```

> p==0.37450938730

The same issue with the `Solve` command.

Answer (score 2):

What version are you using? I get the same result for both in version 12 using exact values

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[p_] := Sum[Binomial[39, k] p^k (1 - p)^(39 - k), {k, 19, 59}]

Solve[f[p] == 1/10, p, Reals] // N

(* {{p -> 0.374509}} *)

Reduce[f[p] == 1/10, p, Reals] // N

(* p == 0.374509 *)
```

Note that since

```
Binomial[39, #] & /@ Range[40, 59]

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

in your `Sum` the upper limit of `k` can be reduced to `39`

Comment: what you get from the following code   Reduce[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = n - 1\), \(3  n - 
      1\)]\((Binomial[2  n - 1, k]\ \ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(k\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 - p)\), \(2  n - 1 - k\)]\ )\)\) == 
   v /. {n -> 20, v -> 0.1}, p, Reals]

Comment: @syz - Your code has syntax errors. Convert to `Raw InputForm` prior to copy and paste.

Comment: Solve[Sum[Binomial[2*n - 1, k]*p^k*(1 - p)^(2*n - 1 - k), {k, n - 1, 3*n - 1}] == v /. {n -> 20, v -> 0.1}, p, Reals]

Comment: Reduce[Sum[Binomial[2*n - 1, k]*p^k*(1 - p)^(2*n - 1 - k), {k, n - 1, 3*n - 1}] == v /. {n -> 20, v -> 0.1}, p, Reals]

Comment: @syz - You again get a bad result due to a precision issue. The resolution is the same, use either `Reduce[... == v /. {n->20, v -> 0.1\`20}, p, Reals]` or `Reduce[... == v /. {n->20, v -> 1/10}, p, Reals] // N`

Answer (score 1):

The solution $p=1$ is clearly wrong.  $\sum_{k=19}^{59} f(p)$ is the sum of terms with $f(p)=0, \quad (k<39)$, indeterminate ($0^0$) at $k=39$ and for $k>39$ we have terms $0 \cdot \frac{1}{0}$, also indeterminate.

Some define $0^0$ to be 1.
Please see https://www.maa.org/book/export/html/116806

Answer (score 0):

```
In[64]:= (\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 19\), \(59\)]\(Binomial[39, 
     k] 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(k\)] 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 - p)\), \(39 - k\)]\)\)) /. {p -> 0.374509}

Out[64]= 0.0999991
```

As @mjw explained, p=1 cannot be correct.  p=0.374509 looks pretty good.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of formatting.  I still haven't figured out how to do that...

Comment: Please take a look at [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: Thank you @MarcoB